# How to fix "File '.../node_modules/dotenv/types' not found." error coming from jsconfig.json?

Tags: visual-studio-code, dotenv, vscode-jsconfig

VSCode is showing errors for jsconfig.json: "File '.../node_modules/dotenv/types' not found."

Appears to be looking for typescript definitions for dotenv, but I'm not using typescript or dotenv (other than in imported packages).  And there is a `node_modules/dotenv/types` folder.

Answer (score 33):

I had the same issue. Restarting VSCode solved the problem. See: https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/issues/475

**Edit:** this seems to be an issue with the contents of dotenv's `package.json`. There's an open PR, but the author hasn't replied/merged yet at this time. Link: https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/pull/476

**Edit 2:** This should now be fixed! `dotenv` v8.4.0 fixes this issue. See https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/releases/tag/v8.4.0.

Comment: Seriously! Sometimes VSCode makes no sense. :|

Comment: Restarting VS Code temporarily hides the problem, but it comes back after a while.

Answer (score 29):

You can exclude type checking for `dotenv`:

```json
// tsconfig.json or jsconfig.json
"typeAcquisition": {
  "exclude": [ "dotenv" ]
}
```

In this way, typescript will not see this library for [auto-type acquisition](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#type-acquisition) and then, *vscode* error will be fixed.

> Keep in mind that the changes affect *vscode* error after a while. Do not assume that see the fix immediately after changing this option.

To see the affection you can restart *vscode* extension server (`Ctrl+Shift+P` And type `Restart Extension Host` and press Enter) and wait a few minutes to validate the solution.

Comment: This is 100% the correct answer, thank you SO much. Even including the `Restart Extension Host` command, which I will be using a LOT.

This has been driving me BONKERS :)

Comment: `Restart Extension Host` rocked my world!

Comment: I added this to jsconfig and it complained `Unknown compiler option 'typeAcquisition'` and the problem came back in few seconds

Comment: @Leonardo Thanks for reporting, Which version of typescript do you use?

Comment: I'm not using ts directly, in fact I'm using a `jsconfig` but I've tried both vscode's version `4.4.3` and node_modules' version `4.5.2` and they both complain about `typeAcquisition` option in jsconfig. And the original errors comes back after few minutes anyway

Comment: @Leonardo Maybe your vscode use another typescript version. As I find in https://json.schemastore.org/jsconfig, the typeAcquisition Requires TypeScript version 2.1 or later. See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling#_using-newer-typescript-versions for more details.

Answer (score 13):

The path `node_modules/dotenv/types` is referenced as the "types" declaration in dotenv's `package.json`.
The problem is that the [types declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html) should point to a file, not a folder.
So it's a problem with dotenv's package, not with VS Code.

There is an [opened PR to fix this problem](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/pull/476); until it's merged, you can edit `node_modules/dotenv/package.json` and replace `"types": "types"`  with `"types": "types/index.d.ts"`.

Answer (score 3):

Just faced the same issue. Deleting `node_modules` and reinstalling all packages fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all mentioned solutions but none fixed it on my end. So, I tried reopening the code editor and the problem was solved

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue and found that adding this to VSCode settings finally fixed it:

```js
  "json.schemas": [
    {
      "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/jsconfig"
    }
  ],
```